# Docker save images twice the size when using powershell - saving raw byte streams

Tags: powershell, docker, cmd, io-redirection

Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

I'm using powershell to build a big project on windows.

When issuing the command

```
docker save docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana > deploy/kibana.docker
```

I'm getting an file 1.4Gb.

Same command run in CMD produces 799Mb image.

Same command run in bash produces 799Mb image.

CMD and Bash takes less than a minute to save an image, while Powershell takes about 10 minutes.

I did not manage to find any normal explanation of this phenomenon in docker or MS docs.

Right now the "solution" is

```
Write-Output "Saving images to files"
cmd /c .\deploy-hack.cmd
```

But I want to find the actual underlying reason for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**PowerShell doesn't support outputting / passing *raw byte streams* through** - any output from an external program such as `docker` is *parsed line by line*, into *strings* and the strings are then re-encoded on output to a file (if necessary).
It is the overhead of parsing, decoding and re-encoding that explains the performance degradation.

**Windows PowerShell's `>` redirection operator produces UTF16-LE ("Unicode") files** by default (whereas PowerShell *Core* uses UTF8), i.e., files that use (at least) *2 bytes per character*. Therefore, it produces files that are **twice the size of raw byte input**<sup>[1]</sup>, because each byte is interpreted as a *character* that receives a 2-byte representation in the output.

Your best bet is to **use `docker save` with the `-o` / `--output` option** to specify the output file (see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)):

```
docker save docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana -o deploy/kibana.docker
```

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, how PowerShell interprets output from external programs depends on the value of `[console]::OutputEncoding`, which, if set to UTF8 (`chcp 65001` on Windows), could situationally interpret *multiple* bytes as a single character. However, on Windows PowerShell the default is determined by the (legacy) system locale's OEM code page, which is always a *single-byte* encoding.</sup>